# How to trigger a job manually in GItlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to trigger a single job manually in GitLab CI/CD. What steps I need to follow?
I have declared environment variable as well but while triggering a pipeline manually, selecting the branch it trigger all other jobs as well.

Comment: is easier, if you provide an example job configuration, so we can better understand your problem and point out solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A Gitlab pipeline is a stream of jobs, by default you can not just execute a single job in isolation.

To work around it, you can use the **rules** keyword https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-rules

Example

```
job1:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: '$execute_job_1 == "true"'
      when: always
    - when: never

job2:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: '$execute_job_2 == "true"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

So if want to execute only job1, you pass the appropriate variable when you run the pipeline

[image]

Comment: I tried.. it didn't worked.
Is there any way to trigger some stage manually? I have several stages and one stage is of viewing Kubernetes logs which I need any time but I need to run that manually. 
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Mmm that's interesting, could you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Below is my gitlab-ci.yml file.